# Font Stacks in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I was reading the [Material Design specs on typography](https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html#typography-typeface) and came across the following:

> For both Android and web properties, the font stack should specify Roboto, Noto, and then sans-serif.

I started reading up on what a font stack is [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/font-stack-definition-3467414) and [here](http://webfonts.info/articles/Getting-started-with-font-stacks) and it appears to make sense on a high-level perspective. However, I'm really unsure of how I'd implement a font stack within Android. Does anyone have ideas on how to be able to achieve this?